# Substitute for solder wire and flux

Tags: soldering, flux

So I am trying to get started soldering, but I was wondering if there was any common household component that I could somehow take out the soldering wire or flux. Although any alternatives will be helpful.

Comment: No. No substitutions. But you can buy lead-free solder. I solder small projects in my house on occasion. It does not seem to create an air quality problem.

Comment: "*... any common household component that I could somehow take out the soldering wire or flux ...*" Take them out of what? Why are you removing both solder and flux? There's nothing left then.

Comment: It would help to know why.  If you live in a 3rd-world country and can't get solder, that's different from if you live in the US and don't want to spread lead around, which is different yet again from just wanting to be really aggressive about DIY.

Comment: Most basic electrical.fabrication can be done with crimp connections, spades, lugs, and wires, requiring no solder .

Comment: Are you wanting to remove solder from stuff so that you can re-use it on other things, or are you just wanting to practice removing solder from things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normal types of electronics work, not really. Solder is an alloy that melts at a low enough temperature that it doesn’t damage components when it’s applied, and it adheres well to copper and brass (hence its use in plumbing.)

If you were thinking about an object with lead to be recycled for solder, don’t. For one thing, pure lead melts at too high a temperature. Solder is a tin-lead alloy or tin-silver-copper alloy for lead-free.

Same story for silver: melting point for the unalloyed metal is too high for soldering. Silver can be used for flame brazing though.

Why bother, anyway? Lead-free solder is widely available (it’s mandatory for plumbing), so working with it poses no health risk other than the flux fumes. Even leaded solder is fairly safe, just wash your hands afterward.

As far as flux, rosin vaporizes when it’s heated and it’s not so great to breathe, use ventilation to draw it away. To answer your second question, most mild acids can be used for flux, but that doesn’t make them any better than rosin (in fact they're probably more harsh.) For example, when I did Tiffany-style stained glass I often used oxalic acid for flux, that wasn’t so great to breathe either.

MORE: different fluxes have different toxicity. Vapor from 'no-clean' fluxes is worse than rosin types. More here: https://www.bhencke.com/blog/2019/3/15/a-hill-to-die-on

I should note that the Apollo Guidance Computer was built without solder or flux. Instead, the wires were bonded to components by spot-welding. Not sure why they did that, weight saving possibly, or eliminating a possible toxic contaminant from the spacecraft. More here: http://www.righto.com/2019/08/reliable-after-50-years-apollo-guidance.html

Comment: "so working with it poses no health risk"  Lead-free solder is much more unhealthy than leaded solder. Instead of lead you get a whole bunch of other more harmful chemicals. Health was never a consideration with RoHS, only the environment.

Comment: Lead-free solder is silver, copper and tin. Leaded solder is lead and tin. Silver, tin and copper, although poisonous in large enough quantities, don't have central nervous system toxicity of lead. Where are you getting your information? Seems factually ... wrong on its face.

Comment: And you are mistaken about the goal of RoHS. It is intended to reduce the presence of harmful substances in the environment *because* of their impact on health - the health of people *and* of the environment generally. Lead dust in particular is very neurotoxic and hard to get rid of. It's why it was banned from paints. Lead being removed from gasoline was for catalysts, but also had the benefit of reducing airborne lead - especially in cities. Some analysts credit lead removal with reduced crime rates post-1970s.

Comment: The issue with lead-free solder is not the metals but the flux, lead-free solder almost always has a higher melting point than leaded solder did which leads to more flux fumes.

Comment: You confuse the flux with the metal alloy. You can get lead-free using rosin, exactly same as leaded solder. The 'bad' fluxes are the ones intended for no-clean.

Comment: @hacktastical From a recent IPC class. It's not the lead or other metals themselves that are harmful, it is the flux. In order to get lead free flux to wet somewhat well, they added more harmful chemicals and you need higher temp. The lead in leaded solder does not typically go into your body unless you grab the solder between your lips etc. But the flux vaporizes and gets straight into your lungs unless you have the professional equipment to take care of it. And no, you cannot possibly solder without flux, so buying solder without it only means that you have to apply even more manually.

Comment: Lead is of course not good for those exposed by the electronic end product, nor the environment. Why RoHS removed it, perhaps rightly so. But the health of the operator was never and aspect they took into consideration.

Comment: That's simply not true. Any place there is lead dust poses a risk. Think for example about folks doing rework. Many of the techniques used to remove solder create solder dust - suction, tip-cleaning, hot-air knives, and so forth. This solder dust not only gets into the air, but also contaminates surfaces near the rework station. Later, when the gear is scrapped, it often gets shipped to places where environmental regulations are lax, and so use unsafe methods to recover ICs and metals. This process poses contamination risk not only to the people doing the work, but also to their environment.

Comment: And then, the point about flux. Like I said, it's not about the specific alloy, but the type of process being used - no clean, reflow, etc. will use different, potentially more-toxic types of flux than rosin. As I said, you can get lead-free rosin-core solder, which would be appropriate for hand assembly, so it is *no different* than using tin-lead rosin core, other than the lack of lead and using a somewhat higher tip temperature.

Comment: @hacktastical What it boils down to is that none of these are healthy, it's just different levels of toxic. Rosin core flux can still give allergic reactions and anyone who's worked with it for many hours without a proper fume extractor knows about the dry throat, general dizziness etc. It's simply nasty no matter the kind.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

The flux is mostly burned away, or at least changes state, during soldering so it can't be reused.

Recovering the solder from scrap boards is in principle possible, but unlikely to be worthwhile unless you want to spend hours and hours on recovering solder for every few minutes spent soldering your actual project.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you might have your reasons for trying to substitute soldering wire, but believe me when I say there is absolutely no way you can do that. At least not practically.

Yes, many soldering tutorials will tell you to buy an expensive soldering station with temperature control, metal sponge, normal wet sponge, tip tinner, and a lot of stuff, and I do agree that for beginners that much of investment is really not necessary. Just buy any 25-35watt soldering iron which directly plugs into mains, preferably with a needle or conical tip, if you will solder on small pads. (***Always*** ensure it has a three prong plug for earth connection for your own safety). And also buy a flux core solder wire. Again, you are not looking for the best of the best, but these two are the bare minimum that you can get away with.

Technically you ***can*** solder without external flux if you have a flux core solder wire, but Since you are a beginner, I recommend getting those small packs of white flux which are dirt cheap. It will make your learning process much easier.  (also note, do not get plumber's flux as it is dangerous for your soldering tip and it will eventually destroy the tip).